# .Tif to .GeoTiff Scaling issue using GDAL

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, georeferencing

I was trying to georeference a .tif file generated from a matplotlib output using GDAL's python bindings and it seems to be off-scale. My objective was to create a geotiff file from the output of a `contourf` function. Code samples are pasted below.

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis('off')
plt.contour(land_reference,levels=[-9999],origin='upper', cmap='gray',extent=(77.53,81.05,28.65,31.49))
plt.contourf(Z, levels=levels,origin='upper', cmap='RdYlGn',extent=(77.53,81.05,28.65,31.49))

fig.canvas.draw()


plt.savefig(r'C:\Users\MRG16-10417\Desktop\New\testspecies.tif',transparent='true',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Then I use GDAL as follows,

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np


src_filename ='C:/Users/MRG16-10417/Desktop/New/testspecies.tif'
dst_filename = 'C:/Users/MRG16-10417/Desktop/New/newspecies.tif'

#The row and column values of the tif file was used here
nrows=252
ncols=386

src_ds = gdal.Open(src_filename)
format = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)

xmin = 77.5000000002060005
xmax = 81.0833333335421997
ymin = 28.6666666666176049
ymax = 31.4999999999532037

# Open destination dataset
dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(dst_filename, src_ds, 0)



xres = (xmax-xmin)/float(ncols)
yres = (ymax-ymin)/float(nrows)
geotransform=(xmin,xres,0,ymax,0, -yres)  

# Set location
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)

# Get raster projection
epsg = 4326
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)
dest_wkt = srs.ExportToWkt()

# Set projection
dst_ds.SetProjection(dest_wkt)

# Close files
dst_ds = None
src_ds = None
```

The resultant image on QGIS,[image]
As you can see the image is slightly off scale and isn't exactly overlapping on the reference .shp file of the same geographic extents and projection.

What could be the reason for this?

Is it because the source image that is incorrect, as matplotlib could be scaling down the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out that `matplotlib` by default interpolates and I was losing a bunch rows/columns, saving that as an image further reduced the overall quality. Setting `interpolation` to `none` and `dpi` at 300, with a little fix to the lat-longs (extend the bbox) helped me overlay the imagery perfectly.

Comment: Great that you found a solution to your problem :) , and thank you for sharing it with the community. Remember to mark your own reply as the accepted answer (yes, you can and should do that)!